# Namespace in RAML file

Tags: api, raml, mulesoft

I'm facing some problems trying to create a RAML unsing Library to define the types for a XML. Looks like is propagating the prefix to all the atributes.

the library is like this:

```
#%RAML 1.0 Library

types:  
  book:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
      title:
        type: string
      author: 
        type: string
    xml:
      prefix: 'smp'
      namespace: 'http://example.com/schema'
      name: 'book'
```

The RAML is this:

```
#%RAML 1.0

title: book test

uses:
  myLib: /libraries/types.raml

/book:
  description: book
  post:    
    body: 
      application/xml:
        type: myLib.book
```

This is the XML that is send for the API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<smp:book xmlns:smp="http://example.com/schema">
    <id>0</id>
    <title>string</title>
    <author>string</author>
</smp:book>
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
{
    "code": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "message": "Invalid schema for content type application/xml. Errors: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'smp:book' is not complete. One of '{\"http://example.com/schema\":id, \"http://example.com/schema\":title, \"http://example.com/schema\":author}' is expected.. "
}
```

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? If so, I can probably help

Comment: yes man, still having this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another answer, to clean up the messy thread and allow the conversation to continue without causing confusion...

Your xsd has two absolutely huge faults.

- You have not declared the global element 'book'. The error message was pretty clear, so that's a miss by you.
- You have not declared a target namespace for the global elements in this XSD

I have changed your XSD below, and it is much more likely to work than the one that you posted. Please give it a try.

```
<schema 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/schema"
>

  <element name="book">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="id" type="byte"/>
        <element name="title" type="string"/>
        <element name="author" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is happening here. In your XML document, the root tag 'book' is in namespace 'http://example.com/schema'. The child tags of 'book' are *not* qualified with a namespace. I have not tried this myself, but I *suspect* that RAML is automatically propagating the namespace of 'book' onto its properties. However, the RAML specification does allow the xml node to be used on Properties as well as Types: [XML Serialization of Type instances](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#xml-serialization-of-type-instances)
So you could modify your definition of 'book' as follows:

```
#%RAML 1.0 Library

types:  
  book:
    type: object
    xml:
      prefix: 'smp'
      namespace: 'http://example.com/schema'
      name: 'book'
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        xml:
          namespace: ''
      title:
        type: string
        xml:
          namespace: ''
      author: 
        type: string
        xml:
          namespace: ''
```

If that does not work, you can replace the entire defintion of the 'book' type with a (manually created) file 'book.xsd'. Make sure that the 'elementFormDefault' attribute on the xs:schema tag is set to 'unqualified'. Then reference book.xsd from your RAML.

even when trying to use a XSD I get a error:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:byte"/>
  <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

the error:

```
{
    "code": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "message": "Invalid schema for content type application/xml. Errors: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'smp:book'.. "
}
```

Comment: It didn't worked, I tried to create the XSD it look like this:
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:byte"/>
  <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
but i got this error 
{
    "code": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "message": "Invalid schema for content type application/xml. Errors: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'smp:book'.. "
}

Comment: I can see what the problem is. Please edit the question and post the xsd there (it is not readable in a comment)

Comment: I see that in the example that I past before for the XSD it was in qualified, I changed and continued receiving the error as in the question

Comment: I have approved your edit - not because I disagree with the reviewers, but in order to move forward and try to resolve this question.