# I have been reading through the specification, but I can’t understand the part about " XML Serialization of Type Instances"

Tags: xml, raml

Using MuleSoft’s API designer I have been trying to test the example given in the specification, using the following code:

**main.raml**

```yaml
#%RAML 1.0
title: test
version: 1

types:
  Person: !include datatypes/Person.raml
  Address: !include datatypes/Address.raml

/customer:
  post:
    body:
      application/xml:
        type: !include datatypes/Person.raml
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/xml:
            type: !include datatypes/Person.raml
```

**Person.raml**

```yaml
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
properties:
  name:
    type: string
    xml:
      attribute: true # serialize it as an XML attribute
      name: fullname # attribute should be called fullname
  addresses:
    type: Address[]
    xml:
      wrapped: false
examples:
  ex1:
    !include ../example/PersonExample.raml
```

**Address.raml**

```yaml
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
 type: object
 properties:
   street: 
     type: string

     xml:
       attribute: true

   city:
     type: string
     xml:
      attribute: true
```

**I don't know whether i create the right Address.raml or not.**

**PersonExample.raml**

```yaml
#%RAML 1.0 NamedExample
value:
  name: TestName
  addresses:
    -
      street: TestStreet 1
      city: TestCity
```

When I test the API this error is returned to me:

```
{
"code": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
"message": "Invalid schema for content type application/xml. Errors: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'type'.. "
}
```

but according to the specification this is the result I should have got:

```xml
<Person fullname="John Doe">
  <addresses>
     <Address>…</Address>
     ...
  </addresses>
</Person>
```

**What I’m I missing?**

**Can anybody please help me to solve this?**

Comment: Might this be a duplicate? It looks a bit like it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195335/namespace-in-raml-file . I found it by searching online for `"Invalid schema for content type" cvc-elt`

Comment: yes i saw the link which you provided but i don't know how to resolve this

Comment: The error from the Mule API is "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR", so I assume that your request XML was wrong in some way. Please can you edit your question and include it. Also, you can supply an example XML message in examples: and it will be validated by Design Center - so no need to deploy a test app.